# copyToNotebook returns OData Feature not implemented

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to hit the copy notebook endpoint in office 365 API, AM getting error 
Below is the request,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/0-E41A205B596D8755!113/copyToNotebook',
headers: 
{ 'postman-token': '02155b4d-a5f9-e389-28ad-21cf0a6b3ed2',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 accept: 'application/json',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxx'
}
body: 
{ id: '0-E41A205B596D8755!122',
 groupId: 'groupId-value',
 renameAs: 'renameAs-value' },
json: true };
```

Response (Status Code `501`)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "20111",
    "message": "OData Feature not implemented. {0}.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0d737ff3-ab68-4284-83b2-91a69216ebe7",
      "date": "2018-05-23T12:56:21"
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest solution here, If i miss something here.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending a valid JSON payload. Make sure you're keys and values are properly quoted:

```
{
  "id": "0-E41A205B596D8755!122",
  "groupId": "groupId-value",
  "renameAs": "renameAs-value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc LaFleur,
I have tried without using those values still im getting the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using those values"? You do need to provide a body payload, it just needs to be valid JSON